# Help, 120 vs 220/240

Tags: air-conditioning

Want to install a ductless a/c in my concrete condo. It is 220 volt only draws max 1300 Watts I have a 15 amp 120 v outdoor outlet available. I know it’s not optimal, but is it doable to convert to 15 amp with a 220 breaker
and change outlet and run it off of that as I can’t run a 12 wire through concrete walls
Many thx

Comment: What is the power requirement for the a/c unit? What kind of plug does it have and what kind of receptacle does it require? Can't you get a small mini-split that runs on 120 V?

Comment: How many wires are at the outlet? Some call 240v 220v but the are the same here in the US for residential for almost everything, in a large facility it may be 120/208 the homes have single phase power but the complex can be fed with 3 phase. You may be able to change that 120v outlet to a 220/240 volt outlet but first you would need to make sure this the only outlet on that circuit, also the model of the system would be needed, I have installed systems that were 240 only (2 hots&ground) but others required a neutral and the neutral was part of the control for the inside unit. More info please

Comment: Are you sure only 1300 watts? That would be around 6 Amps, which isn't much. That would be < 5,000 BTU - not enough to cool even one big room.

Comment: How was the existing wiring to the receptacle here run?

Answer (score 1):

Your ductless system will require 220-volts to operate.  Anything else will damage the unit.  The conventional receptacle near by is of no help.  Besides, even is it was a dedicated circuit and could be converted, you still need a 110-volt receptacle near by for service.   You will need to bring a new 12-Gauge 2-wire circuit to the location.  Good luck. You are gonna love the ductless system.

Comment: Not true. If you have 220V device and you plug it into 110V, it most likely just won't work.
BUT! Here's the catch: Most of today's devices have wide range of voltage input, usually 85-265V, because they contain switching power supply.

Comment: an air conditioner is unlikely to have that.